# Angular 2 import shared operator for Observable

Tags: import, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to use the `shared` operator for Observers but it doesnt works:

My ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/observer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingService {
    private _observer: Observer<string>;
    loading$: Observable<string>;
    constructor() {
        this.loading$ = new Observable<string>(
            observer => this._observer = observer).share();
    }

    toggleLoadingIndicator(name) {
        if (this._observer) {
            this._observer.next(name);
        }
    }
}
```

When I invoke the `.share();` I get the error: TypeError: (intermediate value).share is not a function.

In other case I importing successfully for example the map operator, and using normally like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
this._http.get(this._url, {
    headers: this._headers
}).map(r => r.json()).subscribe(json => {
    console.log(json);
    this.isValid = true;
});
```

So, even if I try to use the `map` operator, to proof the import, in the first scenario `this.loading$ = new Observable<string>(observer => this._observer = observer).map(n => n);` I get the same error.

Comment: Are you getting this error from TSC or from an IDE like WebStorm?  If from tsc, maybe try updating to the latest version of typescript.  If from WS, there is a known issue with the operator imports for rxjs observables that should be resolved in the next patch:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20992#u=1458951972769

Comment: In browser, when I run the app

Comment: What runtime transpiler and version are you using?

Comment: BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler, angular rc1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iuristona's answer works, but only because you're importing the entire library with:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

By importing from only the 'rxjs/Observable' module, you're only importing a few of the methods. Mobile users will appreciate only importing the methods you need rather than the entire library. You can do this with:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';  // added method
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';           // added method
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

So, I dont know why, but when I import from `'rxjs/Rx'`, it works:

```
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```